# How can I get a scroll and cover effect?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I saw this website that had a cool fixed scroll effect, and I'm trying to replicate that. Here's the website: https://templated.co/roadtrip.

Basically, there's a fixed image, and when you scroll the next image comes and covers the first image, without the first image moving.

I don't even know if this is CSS or JavaScript?

I searched many Jquery Plugins but I can't find what i'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure if aware but this link has a download zip where you can pull their code from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image you want to have fixed, i.e. stay while you scroll down, just use the following code:

```
.myImage {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

For more information on that, see [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp).

If you want more advanced options, have a look at [this cool library](https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/parallax.html). (Not affiliated with it.)

Let me know if this helps, or if you have anymore questions.

Comment: That is pretty cool !
This libray inspire me to build an another portfolio ☻
Thank's for the response it was pretty simple actually!

Comment: @Jukker Sure! Good luck!

Comment: Steve, please avoid providing links to w3schools website. They are a parasite, trying to monetize the similarity between their website name and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Consortium/). While the most reliable source of information will always be W3C, the friendliest is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), an open source joint effort of: Mozilla, Google, Microsoft, W3C themselves and others to have an up-to-date, developer friendly database on any and all things web. The nicest thing about MDN is that you'll always find a link to the relevant official docs at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: use Chrome Console -> inspect Element and you will see the "magic"

Comment: You could explain this further so that the user knows why this is the solution you've provided.